# Android: BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: DataSnapshot { key = image, value = https:/firebasestorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble getting my image from the firebase database. Currently I am trying to access the URI using a link. Although am getting an error of BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: DataSnapshot { key = image, value = https:/firebasestorage...

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, final int index) {

        final Message c = messagesList.get(index);

        final String sender = c.getFrom();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(sender);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("image").toString();
                viewHolder.setUserimage(context, imageUrl);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });



        public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            showImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_post_userimage3);
        }


        public void setUserimage(Context context, String imageUrl) {
    Picasso
            .with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .resize(120, 120)
                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                    .into(showImage);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the key value instead of the URL.

Try doing this:

```
imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
```

or

```
imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
```